# How to leave white spaces using $param with Json?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I do:

```
console.log($.param(classNameMap));
```

I get

```
_1987=%20_1987%20fadeOut&=%20%20fadeOut
```

I'd need `_1987 fadeOut` as these need to become classes:

```
<span class="_1987 fadeOut"></span>
```

This is how I get the json:

```
var classNameMap = <?php echo JSON_encode($classesForCountries); ?>;
```

Which gives:

```
{_1987: " _1987 fadeOut", "": "  fadeOut"}
```

Comment: What's the plain object like? Pretty sure you don't need jQuery for serialization/deserialization, that'll only confuse things

Comment: @CertainPerformance this is how I get it `var classNameMap = <?php echo JSON_encode($classesForCountries); ?>;` which gives the json in the question

Comment: You shouldn't create JS on the fly like that - to send data from the server to the page, either use `data-` attributes, or `<script type="application/json">`, or a network request. An empty property name is quite bad as well.

Comment: ehmm actually you gave me an idea, as i am the same value in a data-attribute. But it's for this specific case, in other cases I need to use that php way, surely there is a better solution. Yet the question persists as future ref - me thinks. yes trying to fix the empty issue right now actually.. also duplicating the value fadeOut.. @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `decodeURI($.param(classNameMap))`. The string being printed in the console are encoded. This will decode them. But the answer CertainPerformace is probably what you intended. I'm directly answering to what you asked.

Comment: Yes this answers the question, Certainperfomance was correct indeed, already provided me with an idea in the comment below the question. WIll accept this simply because it is perfectly doing what I've asked. Thanks man

Comment: I'm glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 3):

If the object is `{_1987: " _1987 fadeOut", "": "  fadeOut"}`, then just use ordinary object notation to access values inside it:

```js
const classNameMap = {_1987: " _1987 fadeOut", "": "  fadeOut"};
console.log(classNameMap._1987);
```

Do not use jQuery for that, you'll only make things harder for yourself.

To access the (very bad practice) property of an empty string, use `['']`:

```js
const classNameMap = {_1987: " _1987 fadeOut", "": "  fadeOut"};
console.log(classNameMap['']);
```

Comment: @rob.m Why wouldn't you know `_1987`? Maps are used to map known values to unknown values. Where is this data coming from?

Answer (score 0):

$param is used for creating a string that is suitable for use in a URL.  Therefore it will use '%20' instead of white spaces.

You might want to use Object.values().  That will give you all of the values of the object.
You could then use .join(' ') to turn that into a string.

For example:

```js
Object.values({_1987: " _1987 fadeOut", "": "  fadeOut"}).join(' ')
```

I'd need a bit more context to understand exactly what output you are looking for, but that should put you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following notation to access the values:

```js
const classNameMap = {_1987: " _1987 fadeOut", "": "  fadeOut"};

console.log(classNameMap["_1987"]);

for (const key of Object.keys(classNameMap)) {
   console.log(key, classNameMap[key]);
}
```